# Spark, Scala - Make output from rdd map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to make data report with spark.
The concept I would like to do is below.

```
case class output( txt: String)
outputList: List[output] = ..
myrdd
    .filter( ..)
    .map( 
        some processing
        outputList ::= output( ..) 
    )

// this is why I cannot just union rdd with rdd
anotherRdd.map(
    ...some processing...
    val rdd = ..make rdd from rdd..
    rddinrdd.map( 
         ...some processing...
         outputList ::= output( ..)
    )
)

// save it as text
..save outputList somehow..
```

I know It does not working since outputList would be saved before all output is stored, Is there any way to do this?

Comment: hard to understand. Can you please work on the text a bit. Also can you give an example of an input and the expected output of what you want to achieve?

Comment: why not `union` both RDD after `some processing` in  `anotherRdd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do two things that aren't supported in Spark:

1. Mutate a driver-side object (`outputList`) inside an RDD transformation
2. Work with RDDs inside an RDD transformation (`rddinrdd` is not supported - RDDs exist in driver-side, and transformations on them are done on Executors)

It's hard to suggest alternatives without more specific requirements, but generally, you should **Transform RDDs into an RDD[output]**: that's the way Spark was meant to be used - don't try to construct `outputList`, try to construct an `outputRDD` via transformations.

- For the first rdd, that looks simple - instead of adding `output(..)` to the list, just make that the function's return value - then the result of your `map` operation will be an `RDD[output]`

  ```
  val outRdd1: RDD[output] = myrdd
   .filter( ..)
   .map( 
     some processing
     output( ..) 
   )
  ```
- For the second rdd, you would probably have to **join** the two RDDs on some key, assuming that "..make rdd from rdd.." uses the current record in `anotherRdd`, so generally it would look something like:

  ```
  val outRdd2: RDD[output] = anotherRdd
    .keyBy(..extract join key..)
    .join(myrdd.keyBy(..extract join key..))
    .map(
      ...some processing...
      output(..)
    )
  ```
- Lastly, you can union the resulting RDDs and save the result using `saveAsTextFile`